# [React Native+Firebase]How do you traverse a nested javascript array of objects and print the lowest child. ? (Firebase+React Native)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, firebase, react-native

Im working with firebase and react native. This is the parts of my code that im confused on. Im trying to print out only the 'lat' and 'long' variables. So I guess my question is how could I traverse that far down the array of objects to get to the lower object 'Usercordinate:' and print out 'lat' and 'long'.

```
    /*Imports above*/
export default class Map extends Component {

   state={
     listingData:null
     }


   componentDidMount(){
      firebaseApp
     .database()
     .ref("users/")
     .on("value", snapshot => {
       this.setState({
         listingData: this.snapshotToArray(snapshot)
       });
       console.log(this.state.listingData);
     });
   }


   napshotToArray(snapshot) {
   var returnArr = [];
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
     var item = childSnapshot.val();
     item.key = childSnapshot.key;
     returnArr.push(item);
      });

   return returnArr;
   }

   }//End of map Class
```

This is what it prints out in my console.

```
Array [
 Object {
   "Email": "tim@dan.com",
   "Message": "Hi ",
   "Uid": "Ayb2U4qGc43",
   "Usercordinate": Object {
     "lat": 64.4398281419,
     "long": -168.5352470507,
   },
   "Username": "tim",
   "loggedIn": false,
 },
 Object {
   "Email": "sam@ericson.com",
   "Message": "Hi shadow",
   "Uid": "IK8QcGHp3EcO3FOuFe22",
   "Usercordinate": Object {
     "lat": 34.43982540614,
     "long": -118.53506318966,
   },
   "Username": "sam",
   "loggedIn": true,
 },
]
```

Comment: Only the `lat` and `long` variables of a specific object, or of all objects? Do you want to print them all one at a time or do you want them printed a specific way?

Comment: I want to print the lat and long for each object, I just don't know how to get down to that level.

Answer (score 0):

As **this.state.listingData** is an array you can use .map function.

So to log each lat long of object all u need to do is

`this.state.listingData.map((val) => { 
     console.log('lat:',val.Usercordinate.lat) 
     console.log('long:', val.Usercordinate.long) 
})`